# React Context Provider with multiple values being updated in several places

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and Context and am trying to use a global context provider in React.

```
export const GlobalDataContext = React.createContext({ user: null, textSearchList:[] });
```

user is updated in the same file this way:

```
    return (
  <GlobalDataContext.Provider value={{ currUser: user, textSearchList: []}}>
    {children}
  </GlobalDataContext.Provider>
);
```

I want to use the same context provider to update the textSearchList for a search bar in another component like this:

```
      <GlobalDataContext.Provider value={{textSearchList:this.state.splitSearchList}}>
      <SearchBar
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          this.setState({ value: newValue });
        }}
        onRequestSearch={() => {
          this.setSplitList(this.state.value);
        }}
        style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800
        }}
      />
      {children}
    </GlobalDataContext.Provider>
```

The above code is calling this function:

```
  setSplitList = (searchString) =>{
var splitString = this.state.value.split(" ");
this.state.splitSearchList= splitString;
```

}

I can see that this is not updating the global context because it does not cause a re-rendering at the consumer which is here:

```
<GlobalDataContext.Consumer >
    {({textSearchList})  =>
      <Query query={GET_POSTS} pollInterval={500}>
        {({ data, loading }) => (
          loading
            ? <Loading />
            : <div>
              {data.posts.filter(function(post){
                console.log(`Filtering based on this: ${textSearchList}`);
                return this.textContainsStrings(post.text, textSearchList)
              }).map(post => (
                <div key={post._id}>
                  <PostBox post={post} />
                </div> 
              ))}
            </div>   
        )}
      </Query>
    }
  </GlobalDataContext.Consumer>
```

Is this approach even possible?  If so, then what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have one or multiple `GlobalDataContext.Provider` instances?

Comment: @Daniel There are two instances.  I thought it was clear from the post in that I show it being used twice in two different components.  I export GlobalDataContext once from one file.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should have two `</GlobalDataContext.Consumer>` instances that have common parent (not necessarily direct) `</GlobalDataContext.Provider>` node